# Adding "Add more documents feature" to rails app using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I am trying to add the feature of add more documents to my rails app using carrierwave gem. [I am following this tutorial for it](http://bobintornado.github.io/rails/2015/12/29/Multiple-Images-Uploading-With-CarrierWave-and-PostgreSQL-Array.html). I am getting an error.

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
```

applicationshow.html.erb

```
<p>
  <span class="text-label">Client Last Name:</span>
  <%= @application.user.lastname %>
</p>

<p>
  <span class="text-label">Client First Name:</span>
  <%= link_to @application.user.firstname, user_path(@user) %>
</p>

<p>
  <span class="text-label">Clinic:</span>
  <%= @application.clinic_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <span class="text-label">Applicant name:</span>
  <%= @application.applicant_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <span class="text-label">Application Status:</span>
  <%= @application.status %>
</p>

<% @application.documents.each_with_index do |document, index| #grab the index %>
  <%= image_tag(document.url) %> 
  <%= link_to "Delete", user_application_document_path(@user, @application, index), :method => :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this document?", class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" } %>
<% end %>


<%= form_for([@user, @application]), url: user_application_documents_path(@user, @application), method: :post do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :documents, multiple: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Add More Documents" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

documents_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_user
before_action :set_application

def create
    add_more_documents(documents_params[:documents])
    flash[:error] = "Failed uploading documents" unless @application.save
    redirect_back fallback_location: user_application_path(@user)
  end

private

def set_applicaion
  @applicaion = Applcation.find(params[:application_id])
end  

def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end  

def add_more_documents(new_documents)
    documents = @application.documents 
    documents += new_documents
    @application.documents = documents
end

def documents_params
    params.require(:application).permit({documents: []})
end
```

Please help me locate the error. The error shows on the line for the form to add more documents.

Comment: Just a hunch, but if I remember correctly the comment in `<% @application.documents.each_with_index do |document, index| #grab the index %>` leads to a parsing error in your `erb`. Try removing `#grab the index`

Comment: @alexkucksdorf I tried it but the error is still the same. The error comes on the line <%= form_for([@user, @application]), url: user_application_documents_path(@user, @application), method: :post do |f| %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It a simple misplaced parens. `form_for([@user, @application]),`. It should read:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @application], url: user_application_documents_path(@user, @application), method: :post) do |f| %>
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting ')' ...nt, @application), method: :post do |f| @output_buffer.safe_appe...            _ dont we have to close the parens for ([@user, @application] ?_

Comment: Cr*p. I put the parens in the wrong spot - it should of course be after the last argument but before the block. That line of code is way too long for its own good. Edited.

Comment: You don't need to use `[@user, @application]` if you are passing the `url:` option. Just `@application`.